# How can I set several parameters with a single call of rosparam?

Tags: rosparam, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to set several ROS parameters via a single call of `rosparam` (run in a docker container means loading from .yaml with `rosparam load dump.yaml` is no option for me). Can I use `rosparam set <...>` to get this done somehow? (The [wiki cli docs](http://wiki.ros.org/rosparam#rosparam_set) probably lack something which I could use.)

I tired a single line invocation like follows but got an `yaml.scanner.ScannerError`:

```
$ rosparam set /gains "p: 1.0 i: 1.0 d: 1.0"
...
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<string>", line 1, column 9:
    p: 1.0 i: 1.0 d: 1.0
        ^
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291666/how-can-i-set-several-parameters-with-a-single-call-of-rosparam?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-18**:\

> run in a docker container means loading from .yaml [..] is no option for me

can you explain this? As long as the master is accessible you could even run `rosparam` outside your container and load entire dumps.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-05-18**:
*can you explain this?* I could do so. But I prefer to have the docker environment completely separated from my local workstation OS environment. And if I'd like to load dumps I'd need to handle docker volumes/mounts which I don't like to do in this case.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-05-18**:
`rosparam set /gains "{p : 1.0, i : 1.0, d : 1.0}"` works just fine btw. If you post it as answer I'll accept it...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-18**:\

> And if I'd like to load dumps I'd need to handle docker volumes/mounts which I don't like to do in this case.

use one container to run `rosparam` and target another container? Only volume mount (`-v`) would be the `.yaml` file containing the parameters?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-18**:
Btw: you could also use `rospy.set_param(..)`. As it's an XMLRPC call, it can be used without creating a ROS node.

I would not be surprised if you could use a bare XMLRPC call with the yaml dictionary directly. No ROS needed in that case (but I haven't tried it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I tired a single line invocation like follows but got an `yaml.scanner.ScannerError`

Probably because you're providing invalid markup: abbreviated yaml dictionaries (ie: key-val on a single line) should be structured like so:

```
{ p : 1.0, i : 1.0, d : 1.0 }
```

Note the accolades (`{}`) and item separators (`,`).

---

Edit: Btw: you could also use `rospy.set_param(..)`. As it's an XMLRPC call, it can be used without creating a ROS node.

I would not be surprised if you could use a bare XMLRPC call with the yaml dictionary directly. No ROS needed in that case (but I haven't tried it). See [wiki/ROS/Technical Overview - Parameter Server](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Technical%20Overview#Parameter_Server) and [wiki/ROS/Parameter Server API](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Parameter%20Server%20API).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-05-18**:\

> Edit: Btw: you could also use rospy.set_param(..). As it's an XMLRPC call, it can be used without creating a ROS node.

Thx. I already thought about using [`rospy.set_param_raw`](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Setting_parameters) for [`rospbt`](https://github.com/ros-testing

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-05-22**:\

> I would not be surprised if you could use a bare XMLRPC call with the yaml dictionary directly.

The [docs in the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rosparam#rosparam_set) are wrong about this. Probably I'll take the time to fix it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-22**:
I don't understand? What are they wrong about?

Note that the "Setting an entire namespace of parameters using a YAML dictionary" bit is correct: you can do it like that, but the newlines are required.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-05-22**:
Right. sry, Had a typo when I tried it.